# Как перевести строку со временем в секунды?

Tags: python, строки, datetime

Есть строка с датой и временем в формате:

```
date = "23-01-25 08:48:35"
```

Нужно получить строку с той же датой, но в секундах (от 1970). Как это сделать правильно? Пробовал так:

```
import datetime
date = "23-01-25 08:48:35"
datetime.strptime(date, "%S")
```

Но это выдает ошибку

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 23-01-25 08:48:35

Comment: Так что вы на выходе то хотите получить? Если "35", то `date.split(':')[-1]`. А через `strptime` вам нужно формат всей даты указать, все её элементы.

Comment: @CrazyElf На выходе хочу получить ту же дату, но только в секундах.

Comment: datetime.strptime(date, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp()

Comment: А вообще тут наверняка поиском толпу похожих вопросов можно найти

Comment: Это же дата, хотите получить количество секунд от Рождества Христова?, или от1970 года, или от начала тысячелетия?

Comment: @Oopss от 1970 года

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если от 1970  года:

```
import datetime
date = "23-01-25 08:48:35"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp())
```

Вывод:

```
1674622115.0
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '2023-01-25 08:48:35' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: %Y должен быть большим. Так как год в дате 23, а не 2023